# What do we call this type of person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Person help people very much but not  in case of money.

> A: Can you lift this up?
>
> B: Ya! sure
>
> A: Thanks a lot, you are hulk.
>
> B: Nah!
>
> C: can you please give me 10$.
>
> B: Sorry I don't have. (he lied).

What do we call this type of person?

Comment: So you're asking for a word for someone who is generous with their time and effort, but not generous with money?

Comment: Meaning someone who will offer physical help, of which he he has an effectively unlimited supply (and giving it away results in a net gain for the other but no net loss for him) not a financial supply, of which he has a finite supply and any gift is a net loss to him? *Normal*, I'd hazard. Philosophically, *Utilitarian*.

Comment: Why should he just give him $10? If someone asks you and if you don't give that person the amount which he wanted even though you had it with you, what would you call yourself? You can be called a *liar* since you said you don't have the money.

Comment: I would say he's being sensitive to your feelings.  If he said instead "I have the money but I'll not give it to you" that would leave you feeling worse than him simply saying he does not have the money.

Comment: What kinda person is C, btw? Why does he need $10? Why would anyone give away 10? If it was for charity, maybe I would. If it was borrowing 10, maybe I would. But for no apparent reason? I wouldn't. Does that make me a liar? No. I'm being careful, is all.

Comment: According to A, we should call this person ***Bruce Banner***.

Comment: @johnclifford or **Clark Kent.** ;)

Comment: In the Boy Scouts of America, we speak of volunteers as providing the 3 T's: Time, Talent, and Treasure.  Some give just one, others give all three.  Some give a lot, others just a little.  It doesn't matter.  Everyone is *valuable* and *generous.*

Comment: I don't know what type of person that is, but an /it/ is missing in the "dialogue" Also, I never heard: You are hulk. Perhaps, you are Hulk was meant. Grrgh.

Comment: I doubt there is a single word for this. The two answers given so far are not single-word answers.

Comment: So perhaps someone can add an appropriate tag. For what it's worth, I don't read "what do we call this type of person" as demanding a single word answer. Are tags restrictive in this way? I thought they were more indicative. You can have a single word tag and a phase request tag on the same question, yes?

Comment: "Tight" (refers to money only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an argument for **frugal**, such as this sentence:

'Although he was generous with his time, he was frugal with his money'

> Sparing or economical as regards money or food

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frugal

Comment: So "*frugal with* ***money**", not just "*frugal*". "*Frugal*" just means avoiding waste. Synonyms: *economical*, *sparing*, *scotch*, *stinting*. IOW, "*frugal*" is not a single-word answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest he was being **careful with his money.**

> used humorously about someone who is not as generous with money as
>   they should be

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/careful-with-money

Comment: Not a single-word answer to the question.

Comment: It might be more beneficial to refuse a beggar. There's a difference between _generous_ (giving to worthy causes) and _overgenerous_ (giving in excess, unwisely).